# Unconfirmed transaction why

Tags: transactions

My transaction stays unconfirmed. I've paid a normal fee I quess. The transaction is here:

https://blockchain.info/nl/tx/b8cacc71fba15b4dfee234cd037ba4729a15e573243440257777044f7ed8f101

What can I do to let it through?

Thanks in advance!

Rick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because miners are spaming the network, stay calmed, maybe cancel it and try it later.

Comment: How can I cancel it?

Comment: It depends on the wallet, but it will be automatically cancelled if it stays unconfirmed for a long time. So, do not worry, if the spam ends soon, it will be confirmed, if not it will be cancelled and you will be able to try later.

Comment: As a final advice, I would recomend you to use a wallet that has segwit enabled, it will allow you to pay lower fees and to get confirmed faster

Comment: To add - bitcoins are never lost, or in transit, when a transaction is unconfirmed. The bitcoins are in your wallet, UNTIL the transaction is confirmed and then they are in the recipient's wallet. There is no limbo-state, like there is in traditional banking.

Comment: Aaargh, still not confirmed. I did pay the normal fee. Would have paid more if i knew this. This is not good for the bitcoin in general. Can I pay more fee somehow?

Comment: Yes you can, (if your wallet allows it). But right now the Blockchain is quite crowded, so you would have to pay a higher fee than usuall. I would wait until the mining difficulty adjustment (every two weeks). After that, mining will be more profitable again, and fees will go down.

Comment: Bitcoin is the only truly descentralized cryptocurrency. Miners want to replace it with "Bitcoin Cash" becouse they have total control over it.

Comment: Is there someone here that can push it through for a small fee?

Comment: Fees are going down now https://jochen-hoenicke.de/queue/#2d. With segwit wallets fees are lower. And if the transaction is not urgent, you should time it at the times when fees are low.